# Split DataFrame and apply code to all DataFrames at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, group-by

I would like to separate my DataFrame from twelve rows to three DataFrames by column value, and then apply a set of code to all DataFrames simultaneously.

```
    A     B      C      
 1  A   0.25     0      
 2  A   0.50     0      
 3  A   0.75     0     
 4  B   1.00     1      
 5  B   1.25     1      
 6  B   1.75     1      
 7  C   0.50     1     
 8  C  -0.25     0      
 9  C   1.25     1      
10  D   0.75     1      
11  D  -0.75     0      
12  D  -1.00    -1
```

The resulting DataFrames should be:

```
    A     B      C      
 1  A   0.25     0      
 2  A   0.50     0      
 3  A   0.75     0

 4  B   1.00     1      
 5  B   1.25     1      
 6  B   1.75     1

 7  C   0.50     1     
 8  C  -0.25     0      
 9  C   1.25     1

10  D   0.75     1      
11  D  -0.75     0      
12  D  -1.00    -1
```

So far, I have tried `df.groupby(['A'])` and `df.set_index(['A'])` but theses functions do not seem to allow me to apply a set of code without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest is created `dict` of all `DataFrames` by convert to `tuple` and then to `dict` `groupby` object:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('A')))
print (d)
{'B':    A     B  C
4  B  1.00  1
5  B  1.25  1
6  B  1.75  1, 'A':    A     B  C
1  A  0.25  0
2  A  0.50  0
3  A  0.75  0, 'D':     A     B  C
10  D  0.75  1
11  D -0.75  0
12  D -1.00 -1, 'C':    A     B  C
7  C  0.50  1
8  C -0.25  0
9  C  1.25  1}

print (d['A'])
   A     B  C
1  A  0.25  0
2  A  0.50  0
3  A  0.75  0
```

For apply functions is possible use:

```
for i, x in d.items():
    d[i] = x.mean(axis=1)

print (d['A'])
1    0.125
2    0.250
3    0.375
dtype: float64
```

But better is use `groupby` with custom function - see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    return x.mean(axis=1)

df1 = df.groupby('A').apply(f)
print (df1)
A  1     0.125
   2     0.250
   3     0.375
B  4     1.000
   5     1.125
   6     1.375
C  7     0.750
   8    -0.125
   9     1.125
D  10    0.875
   11   -0.375
   12   -1.000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This solution works as implemented. How do I perform a function in a dictionary tuple? In this example, assigning sum_d = d['A']['C'].sum() would take the sum of column C, but it would not take the sum of all dictionary keys (A,B,C,D) in d['A']. Is it possible to perform a function iterating through all dictionary keys at once?

Comment: No unfortunately not. You have to iterate and apply functions. :(

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through this dictionary of tuples? Ideally I could iterate through this dictionary of tuples as if the DataFrame is once DataFrame (so as to not repeat for keys A,B,C,D).

Comment: Hmm, and iterate in dict is not easier? `for i, x in d.items():
        print (x)` ?

Comment: Not that iterate in dict is not easier necessarily, but I have 20-50 functions that I have to apply to the DataFrame as it stands. Iterating through a dictionary effectively gets rid of the DataFrame.